# Spring boot - @ControllerAdvice doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, nullpointerexception

I am using **Spring Boot 2.3.1**, I try to make a custom `ExceptionHandler`,

Here is my `CustomHandler` class:

```
@ControllerAdvice()
public class AppExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{
    
        @ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class, RuntimeException.class, NullPointerException.class})
        public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAnyException(Exception ex, WebRequest request){
            System.out.println("===>App Exception was callled....!");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(
                    ex, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
      
    }
```

And my project structure:

[image]

I can't get any response from this class, it seems like it was not loaded.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add your AppExceptionHandler class to the component scan? Can you share your configuration classes? Am assuming paranthesis () next to @ControllerAdvice is by mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your package structure is the problem. Since the root package is `id.tarmizi.demoapi` the package name for your handler should be `id.tarmizi.demoapi.exceptions` instead of `id.tarmizi.demoap.exceptions` (an `i` is missing).

Keep in mind that all Spring boot classes should be under the root package, unless you explicitly configure it, see the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html)